# Xcode detach windows/storyboard

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to detach windows in Xcode? Similar to what you can do for the windows in Unity. For example, I'd like to have my storyboard in a separate window on one monitor and another swift file on my other monitor. It would kinda be like running the assistant editor on two different windows. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that double tap on the file name in the left panel will open it in a different window. Is that what you ask?

Comment: thats perfect thank you!